# Getting build task error while running rake db:migrate in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting the following error while running command

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=201504******.
```

Error:

> rake aborted!
>       Don't know how to build task '20150419131135'

Actually i have a migration file already.Now i am connecting to a new database .Here i want to create table in that DB.Please check my below file.

*20150419131135_create_users.rb*:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    if !table_exists? :users
      create_table :users do |t|
        t.string :contact_name
        t.string :login_id
        t.string :password_hash
        t.string :password_salt
        t.string :phone
        t.string :address
        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end
end


class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.down
    drop_table :users if !table_exists?(:users)
  end
end
```

After migrate this I got the above error.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: What about when you do just `rake db:migrate` (without version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.down` and `self.up` methods should be within one `CreateUsers` `class`:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
      create_table :users do |t|
        t.string :contact_name
        t.string :login_id
        t.string :password_hash
        t.string :password_salt
        t.string :phone
        t.string :address
        t.timestamps
      end unless table_exists? :users
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users if table_exists? :users
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be just up and down (instsnce methods)

Comment: @jphager2: In the docs migrations in the Rails 2.3 are written with `self`,  since 3.2 they are written without.

Comment: Ok. The question specifies Rails 3, so maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @jphager2: no, the problem was in splitting methods, as I've stated in the answer.  `self.up` appears to be the older version of  `up`, but it still working as expected, though.

Comment: Ok. So it worked. Not sure why splitting the methods into two class definitions should be a problem. I really hope active record isn't doing any extra parsing of ruby files...

Comment: @jphager2: I meant that this issue it due to splitting methods into classes within one migration: I guess that there would be no error if migrations where separate.

Comment: Yeah but the question is why would that be a problem? I mean presumably the way active record migrations work is that they load the ruby file of the migration, and then run the up, down, and/or change methods on (in rails3+) an instance of the class that matches the filename of the migration ( 20150419131135_create_users.rb => CreateUsers).  So it shouldn't matter that they are in different class definitions.  Presumably you could even require other files or even mix in modules, etc.